# xamarin forms - how get screen brightness and serial ports?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, screen, brightness

I would like to create a page showing all the hardware of the device, including the brightness and the serial ports. How should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want to get **brightness** , using [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) will be a good way.

First implement the interface :

```
public interface IBrightnessService
{
    void SetBrightness(float factor);
    float GetBrightness();
}
```

Then in Forms where you want to get or set methods :

SET:

```
var brightnessService = DependencyService.Get<IBrightnessService>();
brightnessService.SetBrightness((float)0.5);
```

GET:

```
var brightnessService = DependencyService.Get<IBrightnessService>();
Console.WriteLine("brightness is:" + brightnessService.GetBrightness());
```

In Android , create **AndroidBrightnessService** :

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(AndroidBrightnessService))]
namespace App6.Droid
{
    public class AndroidBrightnessService : IBrightnessService
    {
        [Obsolete]
        public float GetBrightness()
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            //var window = ((Activity)Forms.Context).Window;

            //var attributesWindow = new WindowManagerLayoutParams();

            //attributesWindow.CopyFrom(window.Attributes);

            var brightness = Android.Provider.Settings.System.GetInt(MainActivity.thisMainActivity.ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.System.ScreenBrightness);
            //MainActivity.thisMainActivity is a isntance from activity
            //The returned brightness is an int type value between 0 and 255.
            return brightness;
        }

        [Obsolete]
        public void SetBrightness(float brightness)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            var window = ((Activity)Forms.Context).Window;
            //var window = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.Window;
            var attributesWindow = new WindowManagerLayoutParams();

            attributesWindow.CopyFrom(window.Attributes);
            attributesWindow.ScreenBrightness = brightness;

            window.Attributes = attributesWindow;
        }
    }
}
```

Note : MainActivity.thisMainActivity is a isntance from activity:

```
public static MainActivity thisMainActivity;
```

**onCreate** method:

```
thisMainActivity = this;
```

In IOS , Cretae **iOSBrightnessService** :

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(iOSBrightnessService))]
namespace App6.iOS
{
    public class iOSBrightnessService : IBrightnessService
    {
        public float GetBrightness()
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            return (float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Brightness;
        }

        public void SetBrightness(float brightness)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            UIScreen.MainScreen.Brightness = brightness;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: App6 is the name of my project.

=============================================================================

About **serial ports** , I haven't used in my project, however this should exist only in android .I think this needs to be referenced by some libraries (such as .so file) on the basis of DependencyService.

Here is a Nuget Package can be refer ([Xamarin.Android.SerialPort](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.SerialPort/) ).And a  [sample project](https://github.com/Jddl/Xamarin.Android.SerialPort) you can have a look.

Comment: @AccountForRhind No sample code about serial ports , just brightness .

Comment: @AccountForRhind Okey , I will need some time to share the sample link here . By the way , not testing in emulator , just in a real device.

Comment: @AccountForRhind Here is the sample link. https://www.dropbox.com/s/a50w7ls9cj07r84/App6.rar?dl=0

Comment: @AccountForRhind That depends on Project Target FrameWork . If is .Net Standard 2.0 , it will be .Android , else will be .Droid. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: Your code in my project return always -1 (into 'window.Attributes')

Comment: @AccountForRhind Hi , sorry for getting method in android should be this .`var brightness = Android.Provider.Settings.System.GetInt(MainActivity.thisMainActivity.ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.System.ScreenBrightness);` The returned brightness is an int type value between 0 and 255. I have updated answer .

Comment: @AccountForRhind Have a look at updated answer ,it exist in `MainActivity` .Using in `AndroidBrightnessService.cs` .